# How to test loop with jest?

Tags: jestjs

I am new to jest. There is a task to test a cycle.

```
 let values = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        values.push("fizzbuzz");
      } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        values.push("fizz");
      } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        values.push("buzz");
      } else {
        values.push("-");
      }
    }
```

I did the following.

```
require("./fizzBuzzLoop");

describe("loop for with fizzbuzz", () => {
   let values = [];

   test("define a conditions for string values in loop", () => {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
         if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
            values.push("fizzbuzz");
            expect(values).toContain("fizzbuzz");
         } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            values.push("fizz");
            expect(values).toContain("fizz");
         } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            values.push("buzz");
            expect(values).toContain("buzz");
         } else {
            values.push("-");
            expect(values).toContain("-");
         }
      }
   });
});
```

I don't fully understand how the loop should be tested. I will be grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a loop in the test. Wrap the action in a function, run it in the test and offer a comparison option for the result of the function.

For example:

```
function fizzBuzz(n=100) {
  let values = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      values.push("fizzbuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      values.push("fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      values.push("buzz");
    } else {
      values.push("-");
    }
  }
  return values
}
```

And the test looks like:

```
require("./fizzBuzzLoop");

describe("loop for with fizzbuzz", () => {
   test("define a conditions for string values in loop", () => {
      expect(fizzBuzz(15)).toEqual([ '-',
        '-',
        'fizz',
        '-',
        'buzz',
        'fizz',
        '-',
        '-',
        'fizz',
        'buzz',
        '-',
        'fizz',
        '-',
        '-',
        'fizzbuzz' ]);

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more general way

```
        let values = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
       if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
          values.push("fizzbuzz");
       } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
          values.push("fizz");
       } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
          values.push("buzz");
       } else {
          values.push("-");
       }
    }

       module.exports = values;
```

The solution to the problem is done in the forehead. But you can reduce the number of tests and check the entire array for compliance at once.

```
    const values = require('./fizzBuzzLoop');
    
    const expected = ['-',
    '-',
    'fizz',
    '-', 
    'buzz',
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    'buzz', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizzbuzz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    'buzz', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    'buzz', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizzbuzz',
    '-',
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    'buzz', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    'buzz', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizzbuzz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    'buzz', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz',
    'buzz', 
'-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizzbuzz',
    '-',
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    'buzz', 
    'fizz',
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    'buzz', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-',
    'fizzbuzz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz',
    '-', 
    'buzz', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz',
    'buzz', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizzbuzz', 
    '-', 
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    '-', 
    'buzz',
    'fizz',
    '-',
    '-', 
    'fizz', 
    'buzz'];
    
    describe("loop for with fizzbuzz", () => {
       test("check array for matching values", () => {
          expect(expected).toEqual(values);
       });
    });
```